# Using omniauth-google-oauth2 gem in rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

How to do authentication using `omniauth-google-oauth2 gem` in `rails 2.3.8`?
I have installed `omniauth-google-oauth2 gem` of version `0.1.15`. But i dont know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the nice blog post on [Google Authentication](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) for ruby on rails app, just follow the simple steps.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that blog is for google authentication in rails version >=4.2

Comment: Don't worry steps are same

Comment: I tried that but it is giving error as "undefined method `application' for Rails:Module"

Comment: this error is related to rails not `omniauth-google-oauth2`